# r faster load zip sql

Tags: sql, r

I have a ~5GB sql store that I want to read into, and then process with R.
When zipped (gzip) the footprint is ~2.4 GB, or a little less than half the size.

If it has half the footprint, then half the data would have to go through the drive-to-ram "pipe".  It would have to be unzipped in memory though.

Is there a way to import the zipped store into R that is faster than reading the raw, or is reading in the raw my fastest option?

Answer (score 0):

You can read directly from compressed files by wrapping your file with `unz`, `gzfile`, etc.  In your case I believe the format would be:

```
data<-read.csv(gzfile('data.gz','data.csv'))
```